# How is NoClassDefFoundError thrown

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I built a package called "com.hello" in eclipse and I wrote an easy HelloWorld program. Eclipse automatically added "package com.hello;" on top of my program. And HelloWorld.java was put in

```
F:\workspace\helloWorld\src\com\hello;
```

HelloWorld.class was put in

```
F:\workspace\helloWorld\bin\com\hello.
```

It worked very well in Eclipse. But when I entered the directory "`F:\workspace\helloWorld\bin\com\hello`" and used command line with "java HelloWorld," I got `NoClassDefFoundError`. I know it may have something to do with the classpath. But I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is in a package `com.hello`. To run it, you must make sure the **base directory** of the package, which is `F:\workspace\helloWorld\bin` in your case, is in the classpath.

Try running it like this:

```
java -cp F:\workspace\helloWorld\bin com.hello.HelloWorld
```

You can also go to the directory `F:\workspace\helloWorld\bin` and then run it with

```
java com.hello.HelloWorld
```

This will work because Java will use the current directory as the default (if you do not have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set).

Comment: That really works! Thank you very much! I've been learning RMI with command line. And this problem is puzzling me! Thx again~

Answer (score 0):

Go to F:\workspace\helloWorld\bin\ and run it this way:

```
java -cp .; com.hello.HelloWorld
```