# running java from command line

Tags: java

I have been mostly using eclipse so far. Now I'm trying to run java from terminal but I have a problem with packages.

This is my `Main.java` file:

```
package main;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("it's working");
    }
}
```

I compile this using `javac Main.java` and then run with `java Main` which gives me:

```
java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit.
```

**When I remove `package Main` everything works fine. What am I missing?**

`java -version` gives:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Your Java source file locations must (a) match their packaging, and (b) must be taken into account when setting the `java` command's classpath.

Comment: See my answer below, you need to be up in the root directory. Are you running this from within the 'main' directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the java command up one directory level and give it in the fully qualified package name, eg: `java main.Main`

See [How the Java Launcher Finds User Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html#userclass) to learn how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
java main.Main
```

Make sure the `main` (lowercase) package directory is on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your classpath is not set correctly. 
Since you gave your .java file a package it is unnamed no longer.

An example:

```
java -cp ./package1/ main.Main //from the current directory and 
                               //if main package is contained in package1
```

You need to fully qualify the class name.
For future reference if you want to run from the command line you must stop the indirection (for lack of a better term) at the package level. 
Say your class was in the package **package1.package2.Main.java**
I would run it like so **java -cp /blah/blah package1.package2.Main**

Answer (score 0):

### Compile

Windows:
`javac main\Main.java`
Mac:
`javac main/Main.java`

### Run

`java main.Main`

Answer (score 0):

If you add `package Main`, then you must put your source file in folder Main/Main.java. After that you can compile. When you run the program, go to Main folder using "cd", then write `java -cp Main.Main`
See my question similiar to yours [noclassdeffounderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909767/how-is-noclassdeffounderror-thrown)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

In window , you just compile the code as

> javac - d . Main.java

then a package(folder) with the name you specified in your class is created (in your code, package with name "main" is created) in the same path where your program reside...

Then you just run the program as
java main.Main 
    or
java main/Main