# Trouble Compiling and Running Java console application OS X Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, terminal, javac

Cannot compile or run the Hangman console application I created in Eclipse. It is in my `~/Documents` folder on my mac in a package called `hangman`. It doesn't see the two classes `Game` and `Prompter` that I created. I've tried using `-cp` but I'm not sure I am doing it right. It doesn't the ways I've tried it. Any help?

```
HoltnetMacbookAir:hangman godmanliving$ javac -classpath . Hangman.java
Hangman.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    Game game = new Game(args[0]);
    ^
symbol:   class Game
location: class Hangman
Hangman.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    Game game = new Game(args[0]);
                    ^
symbol:   class Game
location: class Hangman
Hangman.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    Prompter prompter = new Prompter(game);
    ^
symbol:   class Prompter
location: class Hangman
Hangman.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    Prompter prompter = new Prompter(game);
                            ^
symbol:   class Prompter
location: class Hangman
4 errors
```

Comment: Can you post the command that you used to compile your program?

Comment: javac -classpath . Hangman.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify all files that need to be compiled.

It looks like in your case it would be something like this:

```
javac -classpath . Hangman.java Game.java Prompter.java
```

References:

[how to compile multiple java source files in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800781/how-to-compile-multiple-java-source-files-in-command-line)

http://www.codejava.net/java-core/tools/using-javac-command

Comment: For the sake of the OP's clarity, the `.` is important because the javac command needs to be explicitly directed to look in the current directory for .class files.

Comment: Following that up with `java -classpath . Hangman` produces the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class Hangman`. This is way more frustrating than I expected.

Comment: @JasonHolt You can only run a class using the java command if it contains a `public static void main(String []args)` method

Comment: @bot thanks for the response. My Hangman class has that main method. Is there anything else I could be missing? Should I open a new topic with a question about it and post my code?

Comment: @JasonHolt Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909767/how-is-noclassdeffounderror-thrown/12909804#12909804  If you are still not able to run, open up a new question and post your code, I'll take a look.